# How to submit a base64 encoded file to paperclip?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, react-native, paperclip

I have a react native application which reads an image file from the device as a `base64` string and submits it through `axios` to a `rails` application. Here's a part of the data that's being submitted:

```
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
```

The problem is, I cannot add this to paperclip directly. What should I do to make it work?

Comment: To downvoter: please consider explaining your choice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Method in model to attach file(`Event` in this example):

```
  def add_picture(picture_64, picture_name)
    picture_data                   = Paperclip.io_adapters.for(picture_64)
    picture_data.original_filename = picture_name
    self.picture = picture_data
  end
```

Method in controller:

```
  def create_picture
    if params[:picture]
      picture_params = params[:picture]
      @event.add_picture(picture_params[:file_data], picture_params[:file_name])
    end
  end
```

In general you just need `Paperclip.io_adapters.for(picture_64)`, that will produce you necessary object that acceptable by `Paperclip`.

Comment: Hi, I got an error saying `Paperclip::AdapterRegistry::NoHandlerError (No handler found for "/9j/4QBYRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgABIdpAAQAAAABAAAAPgESAAQ...`

Comment: Hm....True. Paperclip won't work with data like this. Your picture_64 should have some additional info. Something like prefix.
Valid info type for paperclip looks like.
`data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4QBYRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgABIdpAAQAAAABAAAAPgESAAQ...`
So you need to know file type.
Pattern look like this:

`data:#{file_type};base64,#{encoded64_file}`

Here is [spec](https://github.com/sithobog/events/blob/master/spec/controllers/api/v1/events_controller.rb) for testing controller from answer.